# Eclipse Java Template: Nested variable in :import

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-templates

I want to develop an Eclipse Java Template that is importing a Class, which name is derived from the current Class. `${enclosing_type}` gives me the Class where my cursor is positioned in, lets assume the Qualified Name `com.example.CurrentClass`. `${imp:import(com.example.impl.CurrentClassImpl)}` creates an import of the desired second class.

But if I combine these two part, I will get the Error Message:

> Template has incomplete variables. Type '$$' to enter the dollar character.

Template Code

```
${imp:import(com.example.impl.${enclosing_type}Impl)}
```

If I enclose the inner part in single quotes, no error message, but the `${enclosing_type}` will not be resolved. Double Dollar `$${enclosing_type}` will still bring up the the error message.